# How to test if a specific method is called

Tags: ios, xctest

Hi there,

I am writing unit tests for my app and I am wondering if I can test if a specific method is called.

For instance, let's say I want to test that when the following `dismiss` method is called, the `reallyDismiss` method is also called :

```
- (void)dismiss
{
   [self reallyDismiss];
}
```

Is there something like :

```
- (void)testReallyDismissIsCalledWhenDismissIsCalled
{
    [self.viewController dismiss];
    XCTAssertMethodHasBeenCalled(@"reallyDismiss");
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. You would usually use a mocking library to inject your own version of that method so that you can add an expectation that it's called or subclass the target class so that the subclass can intercept (and forward if required) the method call you're checking for.

Comment: better if you could provide an example also.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code as

```
-(BOOL)dismiss {
   if someCondition {
        [self reallyDismiss];
        return YES;
   } else {
        return NO;
   }
}

- (void)testReallyDismissIsCalledWhenDismissIsCalled
{
    XCTAssertTrue([self.viewController dismiss], @"reallyDismiss");
}
```

Comment: your test calls the method twice and that could well invalidate the logic, it also means adding some logic just to test that you can test that logic...